# Log PHP's mail() function in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

On my Wordpress website, I am using PHP standard mail() function to send emails, instead of the wordpress function wp_mail().

I know logging the emails sent by wp_mail() is easy, as there are plugins that do this.

Is there also an easy way / plugin to log emails sent by the PHP mail() function?

I need to know when emails have been sent, to who, and with what content.

Comment: Use a database to reference and copy data that is then passed to the mailer

Comment: [mail.log](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.mail.log)?